# Como obter o IP público de um usuário conectado via socket?

Tags: java, socket

Preciso obter o endereço IP de um usuário que se conectará remotamente ao meu programa, e lista-lo, o programa em si é um chat onde apenas o servidor armazenará o endereço IP dos usuários. O Cliente se conecta via socket, como proceder para capturar o IP?

Comment: Como o usuário está se conectando com o seu programa? Via sockets, HTTP, alguma outra forma? A resposta vai depender disso.

Comment: Opa, esqueci de esclarecer isso!  já editei a dúvida.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quando você obtiver o socket conectado ao cliente, use o método [`getInetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress()) da classe socket, que ela te dará o IP (entre outras informações) sobre o cliente que está conectado ao seu programa. Com o método [`getAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getAddress()) da class [`InetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) você pode obter o IP do cliente

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int portNumber = 8000;

    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        InetAddress address = clientSocket.getInetAddress();
        byte[] ip = address.getAddress();
        System.out.print("Client IP: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < ip.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(ip[i] & 0xFF);
            if (i < ip.length - 1) System.out.print(".");
        }
        System.out.println();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: esse método eu conheço, pra mim ele só pegava o ip local.

Comment: Não, ele retorna o IP remoto.

Comment: Carlos, só por curiosidade, tem algum motivo para não usar o método [`getHostAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29)?

Comment: @MarcoRhayden Certifique-se de que você está chamando o método `getInetAddress` do cliente e não do servidor. E também que ambos cliente e servidor não estão no mesmo IP. Além disso, é importante ressaltar que se você pretende disponibilizar a conexão via *socket* para terceiros ou publicamente, é bom não confiar absolutamente no número de IP recebido, por exemplo para segurança, pois ele pode ter ser adulterado por alguém mal intencionado.

Comment: @utluiz não, o getHostAddress também funcionaria, depende de como você quer armazenar o IP. No meu exemplo acima seria até melhor (já que o código apenas imprime o IP), mas se você quer ter mais informações sobre o IP (e.g., se o endereço é local), fica mais fácil obter essa informação via o endereço *raw*.

Comment: Bom, este era o método que eu usava, eu fiz a pergunta totalmente errada... kkkkkkk  o que eu quero saber é diferente, eu preciso capturar o ip público do usuário antes dele estabelecer qualquer tipo de conexão..
preciso implementar no meu programa uma captura de ip.

Answer (score -4):

isso tbm funciona

```
<?php

$clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] 
    ?? $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] # when behind cloudflare
    ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'] 
    ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] 
    ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'] 
    ?? $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'] 
    ?? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] 
    ?? '0.0.0.0';

# Earlier than PHP7
$clientIP = '0.0.0.0';

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) {
    # when behind cloudflare
    $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']; 
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])) {
    $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])) {
    $clientIP = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    $clientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

echo "IP do cliente: ". $clientIP;
```