# Programa para captura de IP Público

Tags: java

Preciso implementar em meu programa um método para capturar o IP Público do usuário...
lembrando que este IP deve ser armazenado, antes mesmo do usuário estabelecer qualquer tipo de conexão.

O cliente ao executar o programa, deve chamar um método para a captura deste IP, e o mesmo será armazenado em uma variável dentro deste cliente...

Como devo proceder ?

Comment: Qual é a diferença desta pergunta para [a sua pergunta anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40968/como-obter-o-ip-p%c3%bablico-de-um-usu%c3%a1rio-com-java)?

Comment: a diferença é que a pergunta anterior captura o ip com uma conexão socket.

esta pergunta, precisa de um método para captura do ip antes de qualquer conexão

Comment: E aqui, seria http?

Comment: eu pensei em colocar no programa algo como acessar um site whatismyip por exemplo e armazenar o resultado em alguma variável, porém estou com problemas pra isso : (

Comment: Você quer que esse IP seja obtido no próprio cliente, ou no servidor ao ser contactado por um cliente? Seu último comentário sugere que é algo que não envolve o servidor de nenhuma forma. Poderia dar mais detalhes do que pretende fazer? (fique à vontade para [edit] a pergunta o quanto for necessário)

Comment: @mgibsonbr alterei a pergunta, espero que esteja mais esclarecedor. :)

Answer (score 2):

A maneira mais direta de se obter seu IP público é - como você mesmo sugeriu - acessar um site que vai te retornar essa informação. Se não houver inconvenientes, por que não seu próprio site/aplicação?

Mas se precisar de um serviço externo, há vários que você escolher - nem todos tão simples de usar e/ou gratuitos (o whatismyip.com por exemplo possui uma API, mas somente pra um plano pago, e com limite de requisições diárias). [Aqui tem algumas opções](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2966/return-external-ip#comment), sendo que o mais simples e "sem frescura" é o [**icanhazip.com**](http://icanhazip.com) (ou [**canihazip.com/s**](http://canihazip.com/s)) - ele te retorna o IP e pronto, sem `html`, `body`, nem nada! De modo que para acessá-lo basta fazer:

```
URL url = new URL("http://icanhazip.com/");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String ip = in.readLine();
in.close();
```

Talvez seja interessante - caso sua fonte principal esteja *offline* - tentar algumas fontes alternativas. Outras que retornam o IP "cru" são o [**ifconfig.me/ip**](http://ifconfig.me/ip) e o [**ipinfo.io/ip**](http://ipinfo.io/ip) (mesmo procedimento acima).

**Fonte:** [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3097589/520779)

Comment: Obrigado camarada, eu estava mesmo com essa ideia kkkk,  mais estava tendo problemas na hora de fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Se for HTTP, basta fazer o seguinte servlet

```
package servlet;  

import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  
import javax.servlet.*;  
import javax.servlet.http.*;  

public class ServletIP extends HttpServlet   
{  
   private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";  

   public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException  
   {  
      super.init(config);  
   }  

   public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  
   {  
      response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);  
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
      out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());  
      out.close();  
   }  
}
```

E em seguida o mapeamento:

```
<servlet>  
  <servlet-name>ServletIP</servlet-name>  
  <servlet-class>servlet.ServletIP</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet-name>ServletIp</servlet-name>  
  <url-pattern>/ip</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

Carregando isso num servidor Java EE, mandando qualquer requisição pra www.ENDERECOWEB/contexto_do_conteiner/ip , ele retorna o IP da pessoa.